# my Distinct function is not working and i can't see why c#

Tags: c#

The Distinct function is not working when it should. This is the input I am using:

```
one one two
Distinct
End
```

this is my whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Array.Processing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> texts = input.Split(" ").ToList();
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            int a = 0;
            while (text != "END")
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();
                List<string> infos = text.Split(" ").ToList();
                if (text == "Distinct")
                {
                    texts = texts.Distinct().ToList();

                }
                if (text == "Reverse")
                {
                    texts.Reverse();
                }
                if (infos[0] == "Replace")
                {
                    if (texts.Count > int.Parse(infos[1]) && int.Parse(infos[1]) >= 0)
                    {
                        texts.RemoveAt(int.Parse(infos[1]));
                        texts.Insert(int.Parse(infos[1]), infos[2]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int n = 0; n < a; n++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
            }
            foreach (string info in texts)
            {
                Console.Write(info + " ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and this is the output I am receiving:

```
one one two
```

I can't figure out why both "one" remains. Been looking at the code for over an hour so far and still nothing...

Comment: Absolutely no clue what you're trying to do here. Why not use a .Distinct() om the text variable? You are also doing a case sensitive comparison on "END", and the cases don't match.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code?  _Looking_ at it rarely fixes things.  You may try to name your variables better.  Having `text`, `texts` and `infos` doesn't make _looking_ at your code any easier

Comment: Just by looking at the code I can tell there are multiple logic issues... first `"END" != "End"`, the code also reads a new line as soon as it gets into the first if block, so the `if(text == "Distinct")` will never be true.

Comment: You initially set `text` equal to input from the console before the loop, in which you set `text` again thus disregarding the first input string (unless it's equal to "EXIT", in which case the loop doesn't execute). I would suggest getting rid of the first assignment entirely and changing your `while` loop to a `do...while`. Also the example you provided is not syntactically valid. The `string.Split` method takes an argument of `char`, not `string`, and both your main method and the class it's in need to be public and non-static to be properly recognized as the entry point of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); // one one two
```

Next you have

```
string text = Console.ReadLine(); // Distinct
```

Next, first time inside the `while` you have

```
text = Console.ReadLine(); // End
```

At this point you check `if (text == "Distinct")` but by now its been overwritten to "End" so you never end up calling `Distinct()` on the list.

Comment: @MatinKulev: Just to re-iterate.  Naming your variables better would have helped a lot.  And, stepping through this in a debugger would have presented your problems to you plainly.  Learning how to debug _your_ code is essential